# Label in SKScene not fully left justified in iPhone 6 / 6plus

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am working on ensuring a label always appears in the top-left corner of the screen regardless of what device.

Here is my code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var screenWidth = screenSize.width
        var screenHeight = screenSize.height


        self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit;
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        gameScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        gameScore.text = "Score: 0"
        gameScore.position = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height)
        gameScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
        gameScore.verticalAlignmentMode = .Top
        gameScore.fontSize = 48
        gameScore.zPosition = 1
        addChild(gameScore)


    }
```

On all iPad family devices it appears perfectly to the left, but on the iPhone 6 and 6+ it appears indented about 1/2 an inch to the right.

Any ideas why this would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to answer this in case other beginners like me get stuck!
Be sure to read up on aspect and scaling mode.

I had:

```
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit;
```

But it should be:

```
 self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.Fill;
```

Comment: you technically do not want either,  you are setting the scene size to the view size,  so you want `self.scaleMode = .ResizeFill;`  otherwise your scene size will be equal to the view before auto constraints are applied(Which is why it looks different on iPad and iPhone).  With Resize Fill,  it always makes the scene the size of the view,  so you do not have to worry